# Avraham's Greatness in Holy Middot

Tags: sources-mekorot, abraham, middos-character-traits, kedusha-holiness

Where precisely did Avraham get the greatness he had?

Specifically how did a baal teshuva with an idol worshipping father become a man who only was able to see his wife's spiritual femininity and beauty and never notice her physical beauty?

This seems the most striking case,  of greatness, as it implies absolutely Divine middot, at even the early age of his getting married, before prophecy etc.?

I hope the question is clear - is there a source the tries to explain how Avraham was so *naturally* holy, or so refined so quickly in life with the world against him?

I can understand figuring out Hashem by himself, and I can understand becoming exceptionally holy and refined by the time he had Yitzchak, but this seems to require more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because he wasn't your standard baal teshuva - he was earmarked for greatness by G-d Himself!

[Bereishis Rabbah 14:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.14.6?lang=bi) notes that Avraham was chosen to be the greatest man and was worthy to be created before Adam, however Hashem 'reasoned', "Perhaps Adam will sin and there will be no-one to rectify it, therefore I'll create Adam first and Avraham will come and repair what he spoils.

The Otzar HaMidrashim 399 writes that when Avraham was born, Terach his father gave him into the care of Nachor who taught him idolatry. However, Avraham didn't learn it because "he was set apart for the name of G-d"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed this is a typical answer that I'd like to understand better. Also I think it should say "Perhaps Avraham will sin" no?

Comment: No he was meant to come before Adam, but Hashem knew Adam would ultimately sin and therefore Avraham would come afterwards and remedy this - look inside at the Bereishis Rabbah linked

Comment: The way I read it is Hashem saying "I better make Adam first, because if I make Avraham first and **Avraham sins**, nobody will be able to come and fix it for him, but if I make Adam first and _he_ sins, Avraham will come and fix it for him"

Comment: I think the main thrust of the Midrash is the righteousness of Avraham, i.e. that Avraham had to follow Adam since due to his greatness, any sins that came before would be fixed through him.

Comment: Give me one last chance to change your mind? :) [This Midrash](https://www.sefaria.org/Kohelet_Rabbah.3.11.2) makes the same point but says it explicitly: רַבִּי בּוֹן אָמַר הָיָה רָאוּי אַבְרָהָם לְהִבָּראוֹת קֹדֶם אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן, אֶלָּא אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אִם אֶבְרָא תְּחִלָּה אֶת אַבְרָהָם שֶׁאִם יְקַלְקֵל אֵין מִי יָבוֹא וִיתַקֵּן אַחֲרָיו. See also [this Etz Yosef](https://www.sefaria.org/Etz_Yosef_on_Kohelet_Rabbah.7.13.1.2). This goes with the opinions that we were destined/meant to sin in Gan Eden, so doesn't impugn Avraham

Comment: @RabbiKaii well-argued! :-) It might not impugn (great word!) Avraham but it still demonstrates that he alone had the ability to mesaken and not the other way around.

Comment: Agreed but the wording still should be "perhaps Avraham will sin and there will be no-one to rectify it"

Comment: No because my point is emphasising the second clause - אֶלָּא הֲרֵי אֲנִי בּוֹרֵא אֶת הָאָדָם תְּחִלָּה, שֶׁאִם יְקַלְקֵל יָבוֹא אַבְרָהָם וִיתַקֵּן תַּחְתָּיו